# is there a stand alone JVM that run's on a PC without any OS

Tags: jvm, java

As i know java programs are able to run on any Operating System.
and there are JVM's for any kind of machines.

I need a JVM that runs on my PC stand alone, and not on my OS (windows or any thing else).

I mean a JVM that acts like a boot, instead of the OS boot

i searched for all versions of JVM on "www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp", but i did not get the suitable JVM.

the following link helped me a little but that was not enough

http://java-virtual-machine.net/other.html#jvm

my PC CPU is AMD Athlon(tm) 64X2 Dual Core Processor 5200 + 2.69 GHz

any body can help me to find the suitable jvm version ?!

Comment: there is no support for this JVM from SUN or ORACLE ???

Answer (score 7):

Sure, have a look at **JRockit Virtual Edition**. As I understand it it's basically a micro kernel especially tailored for the JRockit VM.

From [this page](http://realjavasoa.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-without-os-jrockit-virtual-edition.html):

> ***Java without the OS: JRockit Virtual Edition (VE)***
>
> *Am I the only one that's never heard of this before? The Oracle JRockit team is looking at eliminating the OS from the stack required to run Java. This product will be called JRockit VE (not out yet)*

Answer (score 3):

There are two JVMs that I am aware of, which have this property:

The Fiji VM: http://www.fiji-systems.com/index.html

According to http://rtjava.blogspot.com/2009/11/new-real-time-vm-was-born-fiji-vm.html it also runs on bare metal.

The next possibility is JNode: an open source operating system where most parts are written in Java (the rest in assembly): http://www.jnode.org/

JNode is still beta, though.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS)

Good lucking getting hold of it, though, it's nothing more than a historical curiosity.

Comment: No, JavaOS got an inofficial open source "sequel" called "JNode": http://www.jnode.org/

But as far as I know it's still beta.

Answer (score 1):

No.

There was an idea of making a machine that could run a JVM as an actual machine (non virtualized), similiar to LISP machines, but that idea never took off...

You need a host OS to run a JVM.

Googling "java real machine" might give you some interesting articles.

I've found two: [one from 2004](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part3/Chapter24/javaRealMachines.html), talking about how such a machine could be built and [another one](http://connectedplanetonline.com/mag/telecom_real_java_machine/), talking about how JVM runs as a real machine on hardware such as mobile devices.

Still, no dice with a plain PC.