# Bare Metal Java

Tags: java, oracle, jrockit

Here's something I would like to ask about the JVM:

- Is there any free to use Bare Metal JVM server?
- Is there any "proxy" JVM which actually runs bytecodes from a Bare metal server?

For example running a java application on a client machine while the bytecodes are actually executed from the server? Is that possible?

I am currently looking at `Oracle JRockit`, however, I'm not sure whether it fits the job requirements?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  This...doesn't exactly make much sense as it's stated rightnow.

Comment: so basically something like a vmware thinapp? or X windows?

Comment: Define "running a java application on a client machine" in your question.  If the bytecodes are executed on the server, the application is running on the server.  So do you maybe mean that a client machine shows a GUI (maybe through Swing or through a web UI)?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Actually I'm trying to find a solution for our Software lab environment, our desktops are provided by a Xenserver through RDP and we use Thin client for doing coding. So we need to provide a bare metal JVM for performance.

Comment: @MarcB  Not really, more like a Vmware vm or Xenserver vm

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes, the bytecodes are executed by a server on the client's behalf. I am talking about all kind of java application, but most specifically those that we use for Java development tools

Comment: @MarcB On the second thought if you mean like Citrix XepApp, I am also considering it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a stand alone JVM that run's on a PC without any OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504179/is-there-a-stand-alone-jvm-that-runs-on-a-pc-without-any-os)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Core Java as a server on a cut down version of an operating system e.g. linux on a network appliance.

The problem is that the more you strip down, the less functionality you have for managing the device.

The more light weight and smaller the JVM, the less performance you get.  The "full fat" server JVM will provide the best performance for long running applications.

Comment: Actually I'm looking on Oracle JRockit, which is said to be the fastest JVM, which is a "bare metal" JVM I assume. However, I'm not sure if it can be used for this kind of purpose

Comment: I mean, like I setup Eclipse against this JDK and the JDK will route the execution on the "bare metal server", I'm not sure if this is what JRockit is about, what I am certain is that I've read that kind of thing before

Comment: JRockit was the fastest server. Most of the develoeprs are working on the HotSpot server now as its the most popular of the two and if you use one of the latest versions you won't see much difference. In terms of where things are headed, the HotSpot server is the one which is under active development.

Comment: I still don't understand what you believe this "bare metal" server will do for you that the JRE doesn't do currently.

Comment: The term bare metal in virtualization means executing directly without a middle OS on it. I mean as close as possible to the microprocessor. Right?

Comment: Sorry, that makes sense. The only JVM I know of which requires virtualization is Azul, and its not free. AFAIK all other JVMs will run on "bare metal" systems and most of them are free.

Comment: There used to be a "bare metal" very thin OS layer which was called JRockit Virtual Edition, and was a specialized OS that would run directly on a hypervisor without a host OS, and would only run one java (using the JRockit JVM) application instance. This product no longer exists. Other than that, JRockit is a standard JVM, not developed anymore and only for Java 6. Have no input on the 'develop on one machine run on another' part.